# Redirect not working only on a online server

Tags: php, redirect

So I am redirecting from a page if an error appears. I saved the URL I want to redirect to in a configuration file I am including: `require("config.php");`

Inside config.php I stored a variable $errorURL which is set equal to `http://www.mywebsite.com/etc.php`

And in my script I have the following code:

```
header('Location:'.$errorURL.'?&error=dataNotSet');
die();
```

The error variable in the URL is the only thing that changes.

This works perfectly on my localhost but not on the server I have online. I use php 5.5 on both servers.

If I change the redirect part of the code (see above) to:

```
header('Location:http://www.mywebsite.com/etc.php?&error=dataNotSet');
die();
```

It works. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What $errorURL echoes online?

Comment: on what page are you using the `header()` function?

Comment: What do you have ?&error for? I think, that should be ?error=

Comment: You should also have a space after `Location:`. While browsers will be forgiving of that, you shouldn't be outputting invalid headers in the first place.

Comment: how do you set the $errorURL? what page are you redirected to?

Comment: @WaldsonPatricio nothing echoes in the entire script, ´$errorURL´ is used to pass a variable to the next script so that it knows what error message to throw.

Comment: @Jonan I use ´header´ in the file I decided to call etc.php

Comment: @Peter I tried both, neither works. `?&error` worked on my localhost, thats why I kept using it.

Comment: @Escobear $errorURL is set in an external config.php script I set up, just so that I don't need to type it out the every time. You are redirected to another script which just puts out error messages...

Comment: can you access the `$errorURL` variable from the place in your script you need to access it? It's always better to define setting in config files as constants: `define('ERROR_URL', 'http://www.mywebsite.com/etc.php');` (now you can do something like: `header('Location: ' . ERROR_URL . '?error=dataNotSet');
die();`)

Comment: @MarcB Adding a space after `Location:` makes no difference, besides, it was working on my localhost so I don't see why it should stop working online?!

Comment: works-here-but-not-there is rather pointless. "I was smoking a joint in amsterdam and no one cared, then I smoked one at home and now I'm in jail. why?". "Everything's identical except not really".

Comment: @MarcB Well, because the environment is different. That's what I am trying to figure out. What's different on my localhost so that it works?

Comment: I mean what is the content of your $errorURL variable.

Comment: @WaldsonPatricio It contains the URL to the script that outputs my errors. That wasn't the problem though, it was the configuration.php file that had HTML code in it. See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I figured it out.

The reason why nothing worked was because I had a couple of  and  tags at the beginning of my configuration.php file.

Make sure any file included in your script only contains pure php before the redirect!

Answer (score 0):

Proof $errorURL via :

add this line to top of yours code:

```
die($errorURL);
```

And remove dot from start of $errorURL variable.

Probably your $errorURL variable is dirty.

Regards.